# ROS Answers SE migration: launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,all can anyone explain me please ,what the following content of that launchfile (from tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorial/SpawningObjectInSimulation
means???

```
<launch>
  <!-- send table urdf to param server -->
  <param name="table_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find gazebo_worlds)/objects/table.urdf.xacro" />

  <!-- push table_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
  <node name="spawn_table" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param table_description -z 0.01 -model table_model" respawn="false" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

the interesting part for me is :
<node name="spawn_table" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param table_description -z 0.01 -model table_model"

is spawn_table a (standard) node within the gazebo stack?But i cant find that node.i have searched for that within the simulator_gazebo stack.
i only find the spawn_model node,under /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts
question: what is spawn_table?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12476/launch-file/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2011-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"spawn_table" is simply just a name ("name) given to an instance of the executable called "spawn_model" ("type") that is located in package ("pkg") gazebo.

Please see [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML) tutorial for details on the roslaunch XML format.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3